# String path with spaces in TCL not working

Tags: string, tcl, pathname

Why can't i do this in TCL:

```
set path "|C:/Program Files/Example/My Program/prgrm.exe"
```

The string path will get the value:

```
"C:/Program".
```

But if I remove the spaces it will get the full path...
Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because the code for running a subprocess with pipe takes a *Tcl list* after the `|` character. Build and run it like this:

```
set path "C:/Program Files/Example/My Program/prgrm.exe"
set pipe [open |[list $path]]
```

(Later items in that list are the arguments to pass to `prgrm.exe`.)

Comment: I wonder how to create seperate process similar to exe $exepath &;